# Hot to update some record using JPQL?

Tags: java, jpa

I have this code:

```
public void uploadSaveGame(User user, String saveData)
{
    EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();
    TypedQuery<Save> query = em.createQuery("UPDATE WithSave2 SET savedata WHERE u.login = :user", Save.class);              
    query.setParameter("login", user);
    query.setParameter("save", saveData);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

And I am triyng to update column saveData. This is my class WitSave2:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.dke.ps.Tables;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author michal
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "with_save2")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "WithSave2.findAll", query = "SELECT w FROM WithSave2 w")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "WithSave2.findBySaveid", query = "SELECT w FROM WithSave2 w WHERE w.saveid = :saveid")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "WithSave2.findByLogin", query = "SELECT w FROM WithSave2 w WHERE w.login = :login")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "WithSave2.findBySavedata", query = "SELECT w FROM WithSave2 w WHERE w.savedata = :savedata")})
public class WithSave2 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = "saveid")
    @Id
    private Integer saveid;
    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;
    @Column(name = "savedata")
    private String savedata;

    public WithSave2() {
    }

    public Integer getSaveid() {
        return saveid;
    }

    public void setSaveid(Integer saveid) {
        this.saveid = saveid;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getSavedata() {
        return savedata;
    }

    public void setSavedata(String savedata) {
        this.savedata = savedata;
    }

}
```

Is that correct query to update the column? I'm not quite sure especially with this line:

```
query.setParameter("login", user);
        query.setParameter("save", saveData);
```

Could someone help me? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you are trying to update but are performing a select.. also you begin the transaction but do not commit..

Comment: Yes, thats right :) I corrected it (In the original post). If I trying to update the column, it says: Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [UPDATE WithSave2 SET savedata WHERE u.login = :user]. 
[30, 30] The equal sign must be specified.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things for you:

- You have to assign a new value to the column you are changing (not an updated statement otherwise)
- You have to run the query.. not only define it
- As you are using manual transactions its good to add a bit of exception management just in case.
- You dont need a `TypedQuery` when performing a bulk update.

  ```
  EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
  entr.begin();

  try{
    Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE WithSave2 
      SET savedata = :saveData WHERE u.login = :user", Save.class);              
    query.setParameter("login", user);
    query.setParameter("save", saveData);

    query.executeUpdate(); 

    entr.commit();
  }catch(Exception e){
    entr.rollback();
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for answer.   entr.commit(); closes the connection?